# Group by and add values in cypher

Tags: neo4j, group-by, sum, cypher

I did this query on neo4j (Cypher):

```
match (Person)-[KNOWS]->(Comp)
WHERE Comp.name='EN' OR Comp.name='FR' OR Comp.name='CUI'
RETURN Person.fname,
CASE Comp.name
    WHEN 'EN'
    THEN 5
    WHEN 'FR'
    THEN 3
    WHEN 'CUI'
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 END AS Points_Candidat
```

My result is:

```
Yves 3

Yves 1

Alina 3

Alina 1

David 5

David 3
```

But I want to group my result and sum the Points_Candidate for every person. I want to get an answer like this:

```
Yves 4

Alina 4

David 8
```

How do I have to modify my query?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of a collection of numeric values with `SUM`, for instance you can run it on your `CASE` clause,

```
MATCH (Person)-[KNOWS]->(Comp) 
WHERE Comp.name='EN' OR Comp.name='FR' OR Comp.name='CUI' 
RETURN Person.fname, SUM(  
    CASE Comp.name  
        WHEN 'EN'  THEN 5  
        WHEN 'FR'  THEN 3  
        WHEN 'CUI'  THEN 1  
        ELSE 0 
    END 
) AS Points_Candidat
```

I don't know the context, but I think of two minor changes that would give you an equivalent but slightly trimmed down query: 1) since the three tests in the `WHERE` clause are identical except for the value tested for, you can use the `IN` operator with a collection of values instead of a three term disjunction, and 2) since the three `CASE ... WHEN` values exhaust the possibilities of what is bound in the `WHERE` clause, all bound nodes will test true for one of the cases, so you don't need the `ELSE`.

```
MATCH (Person)-[KNOWS]->(Comp) 
WHERE Comp.name IN ['EN' ,'FR','CUI'] 
RETURN Person.fname, SUM(  
    CASE Comp.name  
        WHEN 'EN'  THEN 5  
        WHEN 'FR'  THEN 3  
        WHEN 'CUI'  THEN 1
    END 
) AS Points_Candidat
```

You may also benefit from using labels and indices, and unless the mapping of `Comp.name` to a value is different from query to query you might consider adding it as a property on `Comp` and `RETURN Person.fname, SUM(Comp.Points_Candidat)`.